# Rails 3 Validation - Comparison with database values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to use Rails validations for a form text box to see if the text entered matches any existing values in a specific column of a table in the database. Is this possible with Rails?

Basically, like this:

User enters 'Foobar'

Table column values: 'Foobar,test,house,random'

Validation does not pass because 'Foobar' is already in the database.

Thanks!
dwmcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your model with something like `validates_uniqueness_of :name` or new in Rails 3 you can do multiple validations inline with `validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true`

[From the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks, two more questions: How can I make the matching case insensitive so that the application will not accept 'Foobar' because 'FOOBAR' already exists in the database? And how can I validate the uniqueness of the field based on another table? To clarify, how can I validate that 'Foobar' does not exist in another table in my database? Thanks!

Comment: As for the second part of your question, I do not know. I think that is complex enough to warrant a new question.